# cannot 'yield from' a coroutine object in a non-coroutine generator

Tags: python, generator, python-asyncio, coroutine, event-loop

I try to run a coroutine.i write a correct demo:

```
import asyncio
async def outer():
    print('in outer')
    print('waiting for result1')
    result1 = await phase1()
    print('waiting for result2')
    result2 = await phase2(result1)
    return (result1, result2)


async def phase1():
    print('in phase1')
    return 'result1'


async def phase2(arg):
    print('in phase2')
    return 'result2 derived from {}'.format(arg)


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    return_value = event_loop.run_until_complete(outer())
    print('return value: {!r}'.format(return_value))
finally:
    event_loop.close()
```

I want to know what if the outer function is not a coroutine, so, I remove `async`, and after that:

```
import asyncio


def outer():
    print('in outer')
    print('waiting for result1')
    result1 = yield from phase1()
    print('waiting for result2')
    result2 = yield from phase2(result1)
    return (result1, result2)


async def phase1():
    print('in phase1')
    return 'result1'


async def phase2(arg):
    print('in phase2')
    return 'result2 derived from {}'.format(arg)


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    return_value = event_loop.run_until_complete(outer())
    print('return value: {!r}'.format(return_value))
finally:
    event_loop.close()
```

then i run this event loop ,I find this error.how to explain this error?it not allowed to use a usual function to call coroutine? I used to thought yield from can be used in a usual funciton,but here,absolutly,it could't.who can tell me the reason?

Comment: obviously,this error tell me yield from only used in a coroutine.but I want to know why,because,it can used in a usual generator.

Comment: A coroutine object created with `async def` simply isn't a generator, so you can't `yield from` it.  You _can_ extract a generator from it and yield from that, e.g. `yield from phase1().__await__()`, but I can't see a reason why you would ever want to.

Comment: As a general note, whenever you ask about an error, please include the full traceback of the error.  Most errors can be understood by carefully reading the traceback.

Comment: @SvenMarnach sorry, thank u for ur friendly suggestion,I just sign up stackorverflow just now,this is my first question,i just don't know the rule of stackoverflow,i will remember it.3Q

Comment: @michael: you can still edit your question and add the traceback.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.5+ requires coroutines to be defined with `async def` or `@asyncio.coroutine` for many operations (for example for `await x`) and will throw exceptions if you try to pass anything that does not conform to this.

See [`inspect.isawaitable(object)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.isawaitable) in python 3.5 docs and [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/inspect.py#L209):

```
def isawaitable(object):
    """Return true if object can be passed to an ``await`` expression."""
    return (isinstance(object, types.CoroutineType) or
            isinstance(object, types.GeneratorType) and
                bool(object.gi_code.co_flags & CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE) or
            isinstance(object, collections.abc.Awaitable))
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, hit the check mark icon to accept it :-) see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Good luck in Stack Overflow!